# How to model different return values of a function in a UML Activity-Diagram?

Tags: c, uml, activity-diagram

See the following code for example.
How can I model different return values of a function in a UML Activity-Diagram?

```
typedef enum {CLOSED, OPEN, UNKNOWN} sw_state_t;

sw_state_t read_input(int index)
{
    uint8_t sw_state;

    if (spi_read(&sw_state) == STATUS_OK) {
       if (sw_state & (1 << index))
           return CLOSED;
       else
           return OPEN;
    }

    return UNKNOWN;
}
```

What I want to show is the value the function returns.
What I have is an Activity block with one input ActivityParameter and one output ActivityParameter.

**Update**

Does the following diagram make sense?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a data object, as they are output of activities. Then link the object with the activity

Looking at your diagram, just before each relevant ActivityFinal (return OPEN, CLOSED, UNKNOWN) add an action to return the corresponding object the following way. Then connect each object with the OutputParameter.

[image]

Comment: do you mean an action with a name like "return OPEN"?

Comment: Exactly. Please see the updated diagram... Note that the activity end is now CLOSE, OPEN... instead of "return xxx". That's cleaner and closer to the truth, as ActivityEnd itself does not return anything. It merely marks the kind of the ActivityEnd.

Comment: Just in case - use ObjectFlow to connect Objects with other elements.

Comment: in the object node, is `sw_state_t` the object type and `OPEN` the object state? How do I configure it EA?

Comment: Add somewhere in model an Enumeration element named sw_state_t (usually it would be a class, but you deal with an enum here). Then just drag&drop it (as instance) on the activity diagram. Finally set the object's name. In my models I always create a class model to specify the domain concepts and their relationships. Later I use classes/objects in other diagrams (like this one). This practice makes a nice traceability between different models and permits more formal and acurete spec.

Answer (score 1):

I think your diagram is too fine grained.
Why do you need the internals?

I'd do it simply like that:

[image: Simple]

Answer (score 0):

1. your example with one function is too small, **wider context is missing**. What will be the outcomes of the read_input function used for, the follow ups, how does it integrate into the surrounding system. As @PsiX suggests it is probably too fine grained. Without the broader view modeling single small pieces of code does not make much sense.
2. I'm not an expert myself, still learning → [some links to explanations of the activity diagrams that are useful in my opinion, especially Conrad Bock's articles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23301076/2626313)

   In your case the way to model the result will depend on the way how you want to model the rest, the wider context.
3. If you want to concentrate on **control flow** then you can use e.g. "send signal action"  approach. The "send event"/"receive event" modeling is used by [ARIS Event-Driven Process Chain (EPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_process_chain) visual language where it plays important role. I'm not sure how well does it fit into the UML activity diagram concept but it seems to be "legal"

   [image: focus on control flow]
4. If you want to concentrate on **data flow** then you can use the way electric circuits work (I believe it is the source of the "pin" concept anyway). The activity will send data token through one of the output pins. It will set one of the output wires high. Set one of the bits, return one enum value.

   [image: focus on data flow]