# Class Diagram of CodeIgniter Project

Tags: codeigniter, uml, class-diagram

I am working on a CodeIgniter project. I need to create class diagrams. I just wanted to make sure do I need to make diagrams for model and controller separately? or will it be normal OOP class diagram?

Where can I get class diagram of CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, before anything else you should read topics in the [Help Center - Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), BTW: your question is probably off-topic for this site

Answer (score 0):

What sort of diagrams you need depends on the "why you need to create those diagrams". What will they document. Who will read them and why etc.

You can put many (hundreds) of classes into one diagram. This is usually done when documenting database structures or [Object Relational Mappers (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) using [Entity Relationship Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_relationship_diagram), you can find [many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=enhanced+entity+relation+diagram&biw=1440&bih=799&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X) and some useful tools like [yWorks yED](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html), [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.casestudio.com/enu/default.aspx) on the internet. So if this kind of big class diagram suits your needs then use it

The decision how many diagrams you need is totally up to you, my answer to question [UML diagram for dependency between systems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23301076/2626313) can give you some links to some useful websites.

I don't know if there is some class diagram of *"put_your_favorite_framework_name_here"* already available and if it is part of generated documentation. In case of CodeIgniter it may be available, ask at CodeIgniter's support forums, e.g. [Codeigniter UML class diagram - thread 91800](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/91800/)

If such diagram is not available then you can use e.g. [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect's reverse engineering features](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html) to create it for you

Answer (score 0):

[phUML](https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/phuml) is the best tool I have encountered and only worked for me. You can easily generate a class diagram from your existing code.

Navigate to the folder and try the below command to generate the class diagram on linux

```
./phuml -r /var/www/my_project -graphviz -createAssociations false -neato out.png
```

> phUML is fully automatic UML class diagramm generator written PHP. It
>   is capable of parsing any PHP5 object oriented source code and create
>   an appropriate image representation of the oo structure based on the
>   UML specification.

More info

```
./phuml --help
```