# Understanding the code process of Ccleaner

Tags: java, .net, uml, class-diagram

How does a Register cleaner tool works if you would analyze the code ?

I'm not asking for specific code here...I'm just wondering the code for a tool like Ccleaner for instance is working, roughly explained.

The reason why I ask this is because I want to create an class diagram about the Ccleaner tool.

But ofcourse for Ccleaner specificly you would need the source code..and we all know no normal has acces to the source code of ccleaner

But if anyone know's any registery and pc cleaner tool is getting to it to clean up the mess on your computer and how it's cleaning up your registery...it would help me big time to create an class diagram.

Thanx

Comment: You should first find out what does the Ccleaner do (model the behavior and its environment e.g. PC, Registry, HKCR, HKCU..Uninstall etc.) then you can guess how is it composed internally be envisioning how would you write such a tool by yourself. How would you organize the code. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301076/2626313 answer contains some useful links, first look at how to paper&pencil model behavior on the Agile Modeling website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends much on how you design your application (because this looks like a design exercise more than anything).

First I would recommend you to list down your requirements. Saying "like ccleaner" is just way too broad. Just come up with a list of functionality you need your system to achieve and try to break down such list into smaller responsibilities. Also come up with a list of candidate objects and try to distribute your responsibilities in between those objects, after that you can start thinking in your structure and how to organize them (composition, association, inheritance relationships). Good objects are not anemic (0 responsibily) nor godly (a tons of stuff to do)

That roughly is a way to do it. There is no perfect design nor "a single class diagram" that might answer this question.

Comment: Actually this gives me inspiration...I guess I'll have to do my own 'version' of how I would write the objects and what classes I would create. I guess the biggest job will the about defining and splitting up the broad concept of Ccleaner into little pieces.This will be a big structuring job to get into it...Ill get into it! Anyway thanx for the advice bro! fosa