# Detecting and Deleting unused Files and Folders from phone in android

Tags: android

I want to detect all the files and folders that is currently unused and unnecessary in android mobile.

**For example** if i uninstall an application then files and folders associated to this application are no longer necessary.

For this reason i want to detect such files and folders  and want to delete these file and folders. I have search a lot but can't find any solution. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: there are cleaning apps available such as ccleaner etc

Comment: I want to make my own. @sud

Comment: see this link (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740436/understanding-the-code-process-of-ccleaner]