# From user stories to sequence diagram

Tags: uml, user-stories

I would like to know:

how to convert users stories into sequence diagrams?

and what is the most easy diagram to understand (for customer)?

Comment: Take an expensive class on UML?

Comment: why an expensive class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, what works best with the customers are not use cases. They are too abstract and complicated even for the most of developers. And when they are finally approved, you're never sure whether the customers actually understood them correctly.

I suggest the mix of **UML activity diagrams** and **user interface prototypes** (non UML) as far the best tool to work on this level of analysis with non technical business people.

Activities model their business in an intuitive, easy to understand and clear way. 
UI Prototypes as well, so they can see how they business maps to screens.

Behind the curtains, I like to support activities with a formal and accurate domain class model, invisible to customers of course, but open to developers and making a nice technical backbone of the future system.

**User stories** fit perfectly in this modelling set, you can even make them less formal and more high-level, as the rest will fill the information gap. Sequences can now be build using domain objects, connecting 2 views - customers' and developers'.

I avoid use cases strongly, whenever possible (although I personally like them).

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, a use case is converted into sequence diagrams (through a "use case realization" collaboration for traceability). User stories are different from use cases in that the latter provide a set of distinct steps to take whereas the former concentrate on a need and reason.

If you were to to take a use case, each of the steps in the use case would be represented by messages in the sequence diagram. The use case actor (the "user" in the user story) would be the initiating timeline and a second timeline would be the "system". You could then iterate on that sequence diagram to extract various system components (thereby building a domain model for your application).

Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

### how to convert users stories into sequence diagrams?

There is no straightforward easy way. There is not enough information as user story is basically one or few sentences of text. Converting use cases to sequence diagrams is easier and can be partially automated

### what is the most easy diagram to understand (for customer)?

it depends on who is the customer. In general, overview diagrams, e.g. BPMN style should be easy to read. See [my answer to the question "UML diagram for dependency between systems"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23301076/2626313) for some options and useful links

### suggested readings

- Enterprise Architect video - how to convert use case into a diagram -http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/use-case-analysis/structured-use-case-scenarios.htm
- Enterprise Architect - various ways how to capture requirements and communicate them to stakeholders - http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/requirements.html
- Mike Cohn's page (defined the term "user story") about user stories - http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories
- Alistair Cockburn's page (defined the term "use case") about use cases - http://alistair.cockburn.us/Use+Cases

---

Some examples of tools for creation of sequence diagrams: https://www.websequencediagrams.com/, http://creately.com/diagram-type/uml-sequence-diagrams, you can Google out many more examples both free and payed both online and offline

Comment: @mery we are all glad that we can help and welcome to Stack Overflow. However, correct Stack Overflow way for saying "thanks" is voting or marking an answer as accepted, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @mery I guess you are not a fiber of IBM-watson Artificial Intelligence only pretending to be a human and trying to pass the Turing test (?)

Comment: @mary access to Stack Overflow is not limited to IBM-watson. But your reactions so far (including your recorded profile history) sort of remind the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA AI. No offense, just checking. If you find some of the 3 answers useful, please indicate that by clicking on the "this answer is useful" voting up arrows

Comment: @mery if you edit (improve) your original question I'll remove my downvote. It is locked for me until you edit it. I'm sorry for the initial mistrust

Comment: There is no problem,your comments are welcomed,thank you